# Image not show on web page (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-8

There is a route problem or image address problem. The image is not displaying on some pages but displaying on some pages:

This is the route address in which image is not displaying:

```
Route::get('users/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit-user');
```

and this is the image address of this route:

```
http://localhost/Complain-Management-System/public/users/edit/images/1312455072.jpg
```

and this is the image source on blade:

```
<img src="images/{{ Auth::user()->image }}" class="rounded-circle" width="130" height="130" alt="">
```

The image is displaying good on this route:

```
Route::get('users', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('manage-user');
```

and the image URL of this route is:

```
http://localhost/Complain-Management-System/public/images/1312455072.jpg
```

Can someone please solve this problem, it's important. Thanks

Comment: why your image would be route dependent?? image source will always be the same. `<img src="{{ asset('images/'.Auth::user()->image) }}" class="rounded-circle" width="130" height="130" alt="">`

Comment: I thought it was route problem but it was image source problem

Comment: Your image located on `Complain-Management-System/public/users/edit/images/1312455072.jpg` where `/public` is on your laravel root. So if you give a slash before the `src="/images..."` then it may work. But you give the abosulate path on your image src address

Answer (score 0):

This was the src problem then i try to add the full address like:

```
<img src="/Complain-Management-System/public/images/{{ Auth::user()->image }}" class="rounded-circle" width="130" height="130" alt="">
```

and it works!

Comment: you have change your source again if you change the directory. better use asset helper.